# Inequality for conditional probabilities

Tags: probability, inequality

does somebody have an idea how to prove this proposition:

$A$ arbitrary, $B\subset C$ and $P(B)>0$ => $P(A|C)\ge P(A|B)$.
It should be simple but somehow I cannot get it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Of course wrong in general, try A=B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. Let $B = A, C = \Omega$, then
$$ \mathbb{P}(A|C) = \mathbb{P}(A|\Omega) = \mathbb{P}(A) \leq 1 = \mathbb{P}(A|A) = \mathbb{P}(A|B). $$

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's true. Let $A=B.$